# Identity Server 4 with Azure AD - "We couldn't sign you in. Please try again."

Tags: azure-active-directory, identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm using .NET Core 3.1 with Identity Server 4 and connecting to Azure AD via OpenIdConnect.  I'm using a Vue.js front-end and .NET Core API.  IdentityServer, the front-end, and the API are all hosted on-prem on the same server (same domain). Everything uses https.  I'm using an Oracle database with EF model first, with fully-customized IdentityServer stores and a custom user store (I implemented the interfaces).  I'm using IdentityServer's Quickstart, edited a little to hook up my custom user store instead of the test user.  I'm running this in my dev environment.

If I type in the url to the IdentityServer, I'm redirected to Azure AD, signed-in successfully, and shown this page:

[Grants - successful login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXWW6.png)

The claims are coming back from Azure AD and the auto-provisioning is successful.  It is written successfully to the database.

Authenticating through my JS client hits IdentityServer, redirects to Azure AD, I sign-in, then it redirects to IdentityServer's ExternalController, then redirects back to a Microsoft url, then proceeds to repeat until it finally fails with this page:

[Sign-in failure from Azure AD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X87qZ.png)

My guess is I messed up a redirect uri somewhere.  Here is my code and the **IdentityServer log**:

[IdentityServer Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXn43.png)

That block of logging repeats 6-10 times.  No errors or anything different at the end.

I had to break up the C# code because the site couldn't handle one of my long options lines.

**IdentityServer Startup.cs**:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
            options.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = "/Account/Login";
            options.UserInteraction.LogoutUrl = "/Account/Logout";
            options.Authentication = new AuthenticationOptions()
            {
                CookieLifetime = TimeSpan.FromHours(10),
                CookieSlidingExpiration = true
            };
        }).AddClientStore<ClientStore>()
          .AddCorsPolicyService<CorsPolicyService>()
          .AddResourceStore<ResourceStore>()
          .AddPersistedGrantStore<PersistedGrantStore>()
          .AddProfileService<UserProfileService>();

        services.AddScoped<IUserStore, UserStore>();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // not recommended for production
            builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
        }
        else
        {
            // TODO: Load Signing Credentials for Production.
        }

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddOpenIdConnect("aad", "Azure AD", options =>
            {
```

> ```
>               options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
> ```

```
                options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;

                options.Authority = "https://login.windows.net/[authority]";
                options.CallbackPath = "/callback-aad";
                options.ClientId = "[ClientId]";
                options.RemoteSignOutPath = "/signout-aad";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/signout-callback-aad";

                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = "name",
                    RoleClaimType = "role"
                };
                options.UsePkce = true;
            });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

**Client OIDC config**:

```js
const oidcSettings = {
    authority: '[IdentityServerUrl]',
    client_id: '[ClientId]',
    post_logout_redirect_uri: '[front-end url]/logout-aad',
    redirect_uri: '[front-end url]/callback-aad',
    response_type: 'code',
    save_tokens: true,
    scope: 'openid profile',
}
```

**Callback method being hit for ExternalController**:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Callback()
    {
        // read external identity from the temporary cookie
        var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);
        if (result?.Succeeded != true)
        {
            throw new Exception("External authentication error");
        }

        if (_logger.IsEnabled(LogLevel.Debug))
        {
            var externalClaims = result.Principal.Claims.Select(c => $"{c.Type}: {c.Value}");
            _logger.LogDebug("External claims: {@claims}", externalClaims);
        }

        // lookup our user and external provider info
        var (user, provider, providerUserId, claims) = await FindUserFromExternalProvider(result);
        if (user == null)
        {
            // this might be where you might initiate a custom workflow for user registration
            // in this sample we don't show how that would be done, as our sample implementation
            // simply auto-provisions new external user
            user = await AutoProvisionUser(provider, providerUserId, claims);
        }

        // this allows us to collect any additional claims or properties
        // for the specific protocols used and store them in the local auth cookie.
        // this is typically used to store data needed for signout from those protocols.
        var additionalLocalClaims = new List<Claim>();
        var localSignInProps = new AuthenticationProperties();
        ProcessLoginCallback(result, additionalLocalClaims, localSignInProps);

        // issue authentication cookie for user
        var isuser = new IdentityServerUser(user.SubjectId)
        {
            DisplayName = user.Username,
            IdentityProvider = provider,
            AdditionalClaims = additionalLocalClaims
        };

        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(isuser, localSignInProps);

        // delete temporary cookie used during external authentication
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);

        // retrieve return URL
        var returnUrl = result.Properties.Items["returnUrl"] ?? "~/";

        // check if external login is in the context of an OIDC request
        var context = await _interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl);
        await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent(provider, providerUserId, user.SubjectId, user.Username, true, context?.Client.ClientId));

        if (context != null)
        {
            if (context.IsNativeClient())
            {
                // The client is native, so this change in how to
                // return the response is for better UX for the end user.
                return this.LoadingPage("Redirect", returnUrl);
            }
        }

        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
```

**Azure AD config:**

> redirect uri: [IdentityServer url]/callback-aad

**Database table data:**

[Client table IMG1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFomy.png)

[Client table IMG2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pzrcg.png)

[ClientScopes table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnnK7.png)

[ClientRedirectUris table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10LYk.png)

Please let me know if you need any additional information.  Thank you

Comment: Can you conform this issue is occurring in  all browsers or specific browser

Comment: Same thing happens in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge.  The user comes back as authenticated, but the return uri in ExternalController always returns to Microsoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my custom UserStore. I was getting the user by the Azure AD SubjectId instead of the UserSubjectId.  So in the ExternalController, the ApplicationUser object was coming up as null.  Instead of an exception, it kept going back to Azure AD to try to get the user again, but obviously that just creates an infinite loop.  I didn't think to look there since my user was successfully provisioned with Id's and claims.